# Pytest mock perforce run

Tags: python, pytest, perforce

I am looking for a way to mock a perforce's class method as an instance method inside my class.

Here is what I have

**my_test.py**

```
import P4

class MyTest():
    def __init__(self):
        self.p4 = P4.P4()
        self.p4.connect()
    def run(self):
        self.files = self.p4.run('files', 'my-files-path')
```

Basically, I don't want my unit test to send trigger real perforce connection. Here is my test code.

**test_my_test.py**

```
from my_test import MyTest
from mock import patch
import P4

class Test():
    def test_answer(self):
        mock_p4_return = [
            {'depotFile': '//path1/'},
            {'depotFile': '//path1/'}, 
        ]
        my_test = MyTest()
        with patch.object(P4, 'run', return_value=mock_p4_return):
            my_test.run()
            assert my_test.files == mock_p4_return
```

But I got this error

> AttributeError: <module 'P4' from
> 'c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\P4.pyc'> does not have the attribute
> 'run'

Comment: What if you patch `P4.P4`?

Comment: Oh my god, it works, so the first P4 is what we called module? Do you want to post it as an answer? @Samwise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the module you're testing refers to `P4.P4` (the class `P4` inside the module `P4`), you need to patch `P4.P4` in your test.

If your code did:

```
from P4 import P4
```

then you would only need to use `P4` in both places.

Comment: Thanks, I always feel confused about module import and class.